# merge when not matched with data value from target

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, merge

```
MERGE Table1 AS T USING Table2 AS S ON (T.1 = S.10) 
     WHEN MATCHED AND T.2 = 'testname1' THEN UPDATE SET T.4 = S.11 
     WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (t.3, t.1, t.2, t.4) VALUES (22, S.10, 'testname1', s.11); 

MERGE Table1 AS T USING Table2 AS S ON (T.1 = S.10) 
     WHEN MATCHED AND T.2 = 'testname2' THEN UPDATE SET T.4 = S.11 
     WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (t.3, t.1, t.2, t.4) VALUES (22, S.10, 'testname2', s.11);
```

I need to run this 5 times changing the data for T.2 each time.  The update statements work fine all 5 times but the insert only works for the first run because t.1 now exits in the table and you can not have a when not matched and a reference to a target column.    What I would like is `"WHEN NOT MATCHED AND T.2 <> 'testname2' THEN INSERT ....`
t.1 is the only column you can join on and when done each t.1 should have 5 rows of data with t.2 and t.4 updated to the data from s10 and s.11.  Testname is text and NOT stored in any table.

```
completed data   
22, 1234, testname 1, text 11  
22, 1234, testname 2, text 12  
22, 1234, testname 3, text 13  
22, 1234, testname 4, text 14  
22, 1234, testname 5, text 15
```

How can I get this to work??

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: 2008 Microsoft SQL